# How to analyze-particles as beginner?

Tags: image-processing, imagej, qupath

I am totally new in image analysis and have tried alot with ImageJ or QuPath but unfortunately I can’t find a proper way into it. Here is an image example I would like to quantify:
[image]

Has anyone a recommendation which software I should use or how I can quantify those little “dots” also finding out their position?

I tried it with ImageJ, but the image quality is so bad that it does not allow thresholding…

With thresholding it seems impossible to quantify just the “little dots”…

Comment: OpenCV - Adaptive Threshold ??? 
In simple thresholding, the threshold value is global, i.e., it is same for all the pixels in the image. Adaptive thresholding is the method where the threshold value is calculated for smaller regions and therefore, there will be different threshold values for different regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: result]

you can solve it in simple way using `OpenCV`, or you can go further with more sophisticated approach like [this one](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_holes_and_peaks.html).

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img.png')

mask = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th = 35

mask[mask<th] = 0
mask[mask>0] = 255
mask = np.stack([mask, mask, mask], axis=2)

result = np.hstack((img, mask))

cv2.namedWindow("peaks", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("peaks", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks Bilal! What do you mean with the "sophisticated approach? It looks pretty interesting!

Comment: @Hashriama I mean that it is not very simplified.

Answer (score 0):

I find cv2 complicated and slow. I would do something like this:

```
from osgeo import gdal


thresh = 100 
raster = gdal.Open(r'image.jpg')
# Extract raster band (each band is a primary colour)
img = raster.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(x_start,y_start,x_end,y_end) # reading the image on a specific window, keep empty for whole image.

binary_img = img > thresh
```

Gdal is a great package, but has many dependencies and is a bit harder to install, especially on windows.